# How can I open an URL in a device using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to open an URL in a device connected via USB, as in chrome://inspect/#devices, but using JavaScript. Is there a Chrome API that I can use for this? How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using Node JS or are you trying to do it in the browser? In the browser [WebUSB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB) might help but it is only supported in chromium browsers on https. On node there are many options. The example you gave of chrome://inspect looks to use node.

Comment: @NateLevin my intention was to do it in the browser, I took a look at WebUSB but it seems not to be as high-level as I wanted. My idea was to use something like the code in chrome://inspect, i.e. `chrome.send('open', ['remote', '00c4e68195c9:chrome_devtools_remote', 'twitter.com']);`.
Thanks for your tips, I will take a look on Node JS alternatives!